# Write a function which calculates the number of tweets that were posted per day

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to write a function that returns the number of tweets in a day

Function Specifications:

It should take a pandas dataframe as input.
It should return a new dataframe, grouped by day, with the number of tweets for that day.
The index of the new dataframe should be named Date, and the column of the new dataframe should be 'Tweets', corresponding to the date and number of tweets, respectively.
The date should be formated as yyyy-mm-dd, and should be a datetime object. Hint: look up pd.to_datetime to see how to do this.

This is the twitter dataframe;

```
twitter_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Explore-AI/Public-Data/master/Data/twitter_nov_2019.csv'
twitter_df = pd.read_csv(twitter_url)
twitter_df.head()
```

I have tried this but this function and this is the out put it shows:

```
def number_of_tweets_per_day(df):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':  ['2019-11-30'] * 5 + ['2019-11-29'] * 6,
                   'Tweets': 'x'})
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    
    return df.set_index('Date').resample('D').count().sort_index()
    
    
number_of_tweets_per_day(twitter_df.copy())
```

This is the output i get;

```
           Tweets
Date    
2019-11-29  6
2019-11-30  5
```

This is the expected output i am to get;

```
            Tweets
Date    
2019-11-20  18
2019-11-21  11
2019-11-22  25
2019-11-23  19
2019-11-24  14
2019-11-25  20
2019-11-26  32
2019-11-27  13
2019-11-28  32
2019-11-29  16
```

Comment: You have hardcoded the result in the function, and you are wondering about the result?

Comment: i need a code that arrives at the desired output....my code doesn't....

Comment: Delete the first line in your function, overwriting the df with an example.

Comment: wow! thanks so much @Okapi575, you are an eye opener... thanks alot, much appreciated..